# nested key with json.stringify replacer function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
const result = JSON.stringify({
  drivingLicence: {
    documentNumber: '3333',
    countryOfIssue: 'UNITED_KINGDOM',
    regionOfIssue: 'UK'
  },
  mothersMaidenName: 'AAAAA',
  nationalIdentityCard: {},
  nationalInsuranceNumber: 'NW 26 52 66 A',
  passport: {}
},(key, value) =>{
  console.log(typeof key + ' ' + key);
  return value;
});
```

I get this output:

```
 console.log src/components/Submission/submissionTransformer.test.js:31
  string
console.log src/components/Submission/submissionTransformer.test.js:31
  string drivingLicence
console.log src/components/Submission/submissionTransformer.test.js:31
  string documentNumber
console.log src/components/Submission/submissionTransformer.test.js:31
  string countryOfIssue
console.log src/components/Submission/submissionTransformer.test.js:31
  string regionOfIssue
console.log src/components/Submission/submissionTransformer.test.js:31
  string mothersMaidenName
console.log src/components/Submission/submissionTransformer.test.js:31
  string nationalIdentityCard
console.log src/components/Submission/submissionTransformer.test.js:31
  string nationalInsuranceNumber
console.log src/components/Submission/submissionTransformer.test.js:31
  string passport
```

I do not understand where the first output is coming from.

It says the key is an empty string.  Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal behavior of `JSON.stringify`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> The `replacer` parameter can be either a function or an array. As a function, it takes two parameters, the key and the value being stringified. The object in which the key was found is provided as the replacer's this parameter. **Initially it gets called with an empty key representing the object being stringified**, and it then gets called for each property on the object or array being stringified.

From the [standard](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-json.stringify):

> 12. Return `? SerializeJSONProperty(the empty String, wrapper)`.

That's what `JSON.stringify` returns. [`SerializeJSONProperty`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-serializejsonproperty) expects a `key` and a `value`, which it transforms to JSON using a replacer function.

Comment: Mystified as to why it would pass an empty key and the object being stringified.  Very confused by that.  Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Yeah, I can't really see why that should be useful.